# How to get rid of the integral in this equation $\int\limits_{x_0}^{x}{\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x)\right)^2}dx}$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How to get rid of the integral $\int\limits_{x_0}^{x}{\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x)\right)^2}dx}$ when $f(x)=x^2$?

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you calculated the integrand? What have you tried to solve the resulting integral?

Comment: @JohannesKloos I don't know where should I start.

Comment: First step: What is $\sqrt{1+(\frac{d}{dx} x^2)^2}$?

Comment: A square root that can be expressed like $\sqrt{1+4x^2}$. And now what?

Comment: First step: What is $\frac{d}{dx}x^2$? Plug that in and see where it takes you. Maybe some substitution afterwards with something like a $\sinh$? (remember: $\cosh^2(x)=1+\sinh^2(x)$ ) [edited. sry, got the sign wrong previously]

Comment: Second step: Solve the resulting integral. Hint: use the substitution rule to get rid of the remaining square root.

Comment: The formula describes an arc length of $f(x)$ on $[x_0,x]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_{x_0}^x\!\!\!\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{d}{d\xi}f(\xi)\right)^2}\,d\xi\quad\text{with}\quad f(x)=x^2$$
$$ = \int_{x_0}^x\!\!\!\sqrt{1+4\xi^2}\,d\xi $$

Substituting $2\xi=\sinh(u) \Rightarrow d\xi = \frac{1}{2}\cosh(u)\,du$ results in
$$ \int\!\frac{1}{2}\cosh(u)\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(u)}\,du $$
$$ = \frac{1}{2}\int \cosh^2(u)\, du $$

> Solving this integral with partial integration gives
>   $$ \int_a^b \cosh^2(u)\,du = \left[ \cosh(u)\sinh(u) \right]_{u=a}^{b} - \int_a^b \sinh^2(u)\, du $$
>   $$ = \left[ \cosh(u)\sinh(u) \right]_{u=a}^{b} - \int_a^b \left(\cosh^2(u)-1 \right)\,du $$
>   $$ \Rightarrow \int_a^b \cosh^2(u)\,du = \frac{1}{2}\left(\left[ \cosh(u)\sinh(u) \right]_{u=a}^{b} + (b-a)\right) $$

Pluging in this solution and subsequently undoing the substitution (so we can keep the old limits) gives
$$ \frac{1}{4} \left(\left[ 2\xi\sqrt{1+4\xi^2} \right]_{\xi=x_0}^{x} + (\sinh^{-1}(2x)-\sinh^{-1}(2x_0))\right) $$

Comment: In your final equation, aren't $\xi$ and $x$ the same?

Comment: @Garmen1778 No, you still need to plug in the boundaries. I used $[f(\xi)]_{\xi=x_0}^x$ to denote $f(x)-f(x_0)$.

Answer (score 4):

As in other answers, let $2x=\tan(\theta)$
$$
\begin{align}
\int\sqrt{1+4x^2}\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac12\int\sec(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\tan(\theta)\\
&=\frac12\int\sec^4(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\sin(\theta)\\
&=\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}\sin(\theta)}{(1-\sin^2(\theta))^2}\\
&=\frac18\int\left({\small\frac{1}{1-\sin(\theta)}+\frac{1}{(1-\sin(\theta))^2}+\frac{1}{1+\sin(\theta)}+\frac{1}{(1+\sin(\theta))^2}}\right)\mathrm{d}\sin(\theta)\\
&=\frac18\left(\log\left(\frac{1+\sin(\theta)}{1-\sin(\theta)}\right)+\frac{1}{1-\sin(\theta)}-\frac{1}{1+\sin(\theta)}\right)+C\\
&=\frac14\left(\log\left(\tan(\theta)+\sec(\theta)\right)+\tan(\theta)\sec(\theta)\right)+C\\
&=\frac14\log\left(2x+\sqrt{1+4x^2}\right)+\frac12x\sqrt{1+4x^2}+C\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Then take the difference of $(1)$ at the limits of integration.

Answer (score 2):

Summarising the comments, you'll get
$$
\int\limits_{x_0}^{x}{\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{d}{dt}f(t)\right)^2}dt}
=\int\limits_{x_0}^{x}{\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{d}{dt}t^2\right)^2}dt}
=\int\limits_{x_0}^{x}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}dt}
$$
To [solve](http://tinyurl.com/cm4juf4) the last one substitute $t=\tan(u)/2$ and $dt=\sec^2(u)/2du$. Then $\sqrt{1+4t^2}= \sqrt{\tan^2(u)+1}=\sec(u)$, so we get as antiderviative:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{2}\int \sec^3(u) du&=&\frac{1}{4}\tan(u)\sec(u)+\frac{1}{4}\int \sec(u)du+\text{const.}\\
&=&\frac{1}{4}\tan(u)\sec(u)+\frac{1}{4}\log(\tan(u)+\sec(u))+\text{const.} \\
&=& \frac{t}{2}\sqrt{1+4t^2}+\frac{1}{4}\log(2t+\sqrt{1+4t^2})+\text{const.}\\
&=& \frac{1}{4}\left(2t\sqrt{1+4t^2}+\sinh^{-1}(2t) \right)+\text{const.}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Put in your limits and your done:
$$
\int\limits_{x_0}^{x}{\sqrt{1+4t^2}dx}=\left[\frac{1}{4}\left(2t\sqrt{1+4t^2}+\sinh^{-1}(2t) \right) \right]_{x_0}^x
$$

Comment: "putting in the limits" will not give you the "const.." term that should be well defined as the initial integral has both limits given.

Comment: @example thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the basics!
You need a derivative of the curve to begin with.

If the integrand has root of sum of squares in the denom
Immediately draw a right triangle with appropriate sides and the rest is an algebraic walk.